# Typo3 is not sending post data to contact form

Tags: php, post, typo3

I'm working on a `typo3`-based system (Version 4.7), and trying to get the contact-email-form to work. It is a fairly simple one (Name, Email, some fields like Adress and a Question Text) to send a simple text based email. The plugin I'm currently using is `powermail`.

When testing this form on my local version of the system it is sending the email to my adress without a problem - on the live system, however, it only displays the message

```
An error occurred while trying to call Tx_Powermail_Controller_FormsController->createAction(). Error: Required property 'form' does not exist.
```

**what I already know:**

The Problem seems to be that the html form is not submitting any `POST` data to the extension controller and therefore it has nothing to work with and is displaying that error ...

This is **not** a problem with powermail, building the form with other extensions (`mailformplus`, the built-in `form` plugin ...) has the same problem: no post data is sent.

It's also not a problem with POST-data on that server in general, calling a simple test script like this:

```
<form method="post" action="test.php?gettest=1" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="text" name="test" value="" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Testen" />
</form>
```

from a script **not** in the typo3-system displays

```
GET:

array (size=1)
  'gettest' => string '1' (length=1)

POST:

array (size=2)
  'test' => string 'test' (length=4)
  'submit' => string 'Testen' (length=6)
```

correctly in `test.php` (which is just a `var_dump($_POST/$_GET)`).

However, building the above as a page in the typo3 system shows shows an empty POST array in `test.php`.

The problem is the same with `realurl` disabled.

Now my question is, could there be anything else in typo3 rewriting/redirecting request that POST-data might get lost? As I said, my local system works and I really can't findd any configuration difference between those two ... (but I'm also still far away from understanding every bit of the typo3 CMS' internal working)

Comment: Maybe some anti-spam extension like wt_spamshield is interfering?

Comment: @Jost there is `sfpantispam` installed, but i can't find a configuration there that would interfere... or is different than on my local system

Comment: Try uninstalling `sfantispam`on the live system; then again, also check for suhosin and mod_security on the server, they can interfere as well with post data if they don't like it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It finally works now, and it was a rather stupidly simple issue with the webserver.

It rewrote requests to this site to use `http://example.de` as a refferer, whereas the links generated from Typo3 used `http://www.example.de` (because I entered that as `config.baseUrl`).

The normal pages didn't have any problem with that, but everytime a `POST`-form was used from within Typo3 it resulted in the `POST`-data not being send, resulting in above mentioned error from Powermail (and all other email plugins).

So the solution was setting the `config.baseUrl` to `http://example.de`, the exact same the webserver rewrote requests to.

I hope maybe this can help someone else having a similar problem someday ;)

Comment: definetly helped me a lot! Thanks for posting this :)